# Sorting not working on some fields using Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have the following code
DataProvider:

```
  public function search() {
   $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
    $criteria->compare('firstname', $this->firstname, true);
    $criteria->compare('lastname', $this->lastname, true);
    $criteria->compare('email', $this->email, true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria' => $criteria,
                'pagination' => array(
                    'pageSize' => 20
                ),
                'sort' => array(
                    'defaultOrder' => 'id DESC'
                )
            ));
}
```

GridView:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'id','htmlOptions'=>array( 'width'=>'10%' )),
        array('name'=>'email','htmlOptions'=>array( 'width'=>'15%' )),
        array('name' => 'firstName', 'htmlOptions'=>array( 'width'=>'10%' ), 'value'=>'$data->firstname'),
        array('name' => 'lastName', 'htmlOptions'=>array( 'width'=>'10%' ), 'value' => '$data->lastname'),

    ),
));
```

Now when I view this grid the sorting works on Id, email fields but not working on firstName, lastName

Can anybody tell me whats the problem with sorting on firsttName and lastName while it works fine on id and email fields?

Comment: Can you please post the code that belongs to `$criteria`? Most likely the problem occurs over there.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I updated my question with search function.

Comment: Looks good so far. Are you sure the first- and lastname are filled with contents? There massive assigned, so if there is no rule for them the fields won't be filled.

Comment: Yes I can see the values of id, email, firstname and lastname in grid.

Comment: You have spelled `firstName` and `lastName` with a capital `N`. Did you try lowercase?

Comment: No, i don't mean in the gridview :-). In the `actionAdmin()` function in your controller there is this line: `$model->attributes=$_GET['Product'];` What do you see if you put this line after that line: `echo $model->firstname;`?

Comment: Great lowercase works but I have "Firstname" and "Lastname" in header, I want it to be "First Name" and "Last Name".

Comment: Try to add `'header'=>'First Name'` to the array, or set the `attributeLabels` in your model. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#columns-detail

Comment: It works fine now, Thanks to both of you,  Michiel and Joh